# jQuery & CORS always fail on an open remote server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I'm trying to simulate a POST, with jQuery `$.ajax()` method, on a remote server which is supposed to have CORS enabled.

The idea is to submit a form with username/password provided and get the cookie delivered by the server from a successful authentication.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    url: this.url,
    data: {
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password
    },
    xhrFields: {
        withCreditentials: true
    },
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.info(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());
    },
    error: function(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.warn(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Here is the response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache,max-age=0,must-revalidate
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

And the request headers:

```
Accept: * / *
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: fr,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Host: my remote server (URL is hidden)
```

The problem is that I get a *console.warn* telling me:

```
Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'URL'
```

I also tried with a Chrome extension which simulate a POST: I put the same data as in my jQuery and everything succeed, from the call to the cookie delivered once the form is submitted.

I don't understand how my jQuery fails to load the URL but is giving me a **200 OK** anyway! And I don't understand how to make it right!

Where I'm doing a mistake?

Comment: No CORS enabled there.

Comment: @MinusFour how can you tell? my sysadmin told me the CORS **is** enabled, and the chrome extension succeed

Comment: @PierreLeBot there would be an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` **response** header

Comment: We cannot see `this` in  `data{ username: this.username, password: this.password}`.

Comment: @PHPglue don't really need to see what `this` is, and it would just add bloat to the question. This is likely a CORS issue which I addressed below.

Comment: @PHPglue: it is defined elsewhere, nothing important here.

Comment: It was just a comment. I voted up the comments I agree with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that you need to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin： *` header to the api response header. Your REST client (the chrome extension) doesn't abide by CORS rules like the browser, which is why it works.

Comment: OK thanks, but I guess this is something server-side, right?

Comment: OK, let me see with the sysadmin and I'll get back to you (and validate your answer). This modification should be enough? Is my jQuery correct?

Comment: @PierreLeBot The jQuery appears to be fine.

Comment: @PierreLeBot it's highly unlikely you need to set the `crossDomain` property

Comment: @PierreLeBot Elaborating on what phil said... you should only have to set the crossDomain property if you are trying to "force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same domain" because by default, if you are making a cross domain request, the property is set to true. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.